# JSPDF create and attach to email

Tags: php, ajax, email, pdf, jspdf

I have some problems in send a mail with attachments. The attachment file is a pdf generated by JSPDF library. Firstly I start to generate the pdf and call the script PHP with Ajax, like the code below:

```
var pdf = doc.output(); 
$.post(
     "/smt/mail.php", 
     { 
          data: pdf 
      }, 
     function(data) {
         console.log(data.resultado); 
     }
 , 'json');
```

Also i tried with the line of code `pdf = btoa(doc.output());`
but the error seems the same.
In the script PHP I have:

```
  $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";    

  // multipart boundary 
  $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-  8\"\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 

  // preparing attachments
  if(count($files) > 0){
  for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
      if(is_file($files[$i])){

        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $fp =    fopen($files[$i],"rb");
        $data =  fread($fp,filesize($files[$i]));
        fclose($fp);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"\n" . 
        "Content-Description: ".basename($files[$i])."\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($files[$i]).";\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
       }
 }
 }
 $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";


 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
 try{
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
 //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 //$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
 $mail->Host = 'mail2.mailbox.pt';
 $mail->Username   = "****"; // SMTP account username example
 $mail->Password   = "****";        // SMTP account password example
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
 $mail->Port = 587;    
 $mail->From = "***";
 $mail->FromName = "******";
 $mail->AddAddress($to, "Test"); 
 $mail->AddReplyTo("****", '*****');
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
 $mail->Subject = $subject;
 $mail->Body    =  $message;

 $mail->Send()
```

With this code I can sent the mail, but without attachement, after a little debug I can see that the condition `if(is_file[$i])` returns false.

Anyone can help me?

Thank You

Comment: I have read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184325/is-file-fails-on-passed-pdf-file, and it help me with my problem.

No I hae another problem, in email sent the attached file is not a file that I can make a download but a big code in the message body

Comment: You can try converting the base64 format into a PDF store in the temporary place in the server. Then read attach that file as a mail attachment and send it. After sending mail delete that file. I don't know how to do that in PHP but i have done that in C#. Check my repo you could get some idea https://github.com/Purush0th/PDFnMail

Comment: Thank You @Purushoth for your help, I have success using the addAttachment function of PHP to attach pdf to the mail.

Comment: That's great! Please add the implementation as the answer so it will help others.

Comment: Yes, is a good idea :D

Comment: Yes, is a good idea :D to attach a file into a mail I put the file created by JSPDF in a local in server with this code `$name = $_POST['name']; $file = $_POST['data'];
    $filePath = 'tmp/Relatório Clínico - '.$name.'.pdf';
    file_put_contents($filePath, base64_decode($file));`  and pass the variable `$filePath` to the function that sent mail. In this function when create the mail I simple do `$mail->AddAttachment($filePath); `. And it works for me. With this code I don't need to make a cycle for to attached all files in the array.